# Home_path issue with RoR testing locally on mobile device

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile, localhost

When I use

```
<%= link_to image_tag("foo.png"), home_path %>
```

and display it on my localhost on my iPhone, it's broken.  When I inspect on with firebug, the `src` of the image is `http://localhost:3000/images/foo.png` thus causing it to break on my iPhone.

When I use

```
<img src="/images/foo.png" />
```

it displays fine on my iPhone.  I am pointing to the IP address of my PC running the server of my rails app in Safari.  It's loading the text but all the `css`, JavaScript, and images are missing unless the path is absolute with using the rails default helpers.

Is there a way to correct this path issue locally so it's absolute like `/images/foo.png` instead of `http://localhost:3000/images/foo.png`.

**Update**

CSS file paths are also affected.  Instead of just making the path `/stylesheets/foo.css`, it's `http://localhost:3000/stylesheets/foo.css`.

**Update: Solution**

It's the Facebook plugin changing the asset host to the callback url of my facebook app settings which is currently set to `http://localhost:3000/`

Comment: You should've posted your own solution as an answer (and accept it) so this question doesnt show up as unanswered in overviews.

Comment: @Nils Reidermann - Thanks.  Will do!

Answer (score 0):

It's the facebooker plugin changing the asset host to the callback url of my facebook app settings which is currently set to http://localhost:3000/

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue until a few minutes back in my **Rails app that was using Facebooker plugin** where all asset routes were being overwritten. The symptom of this was errors like

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/runfbrun//stylesheets/facebooker.css" with {:method=>:get, :canvas=>false}):
```

I finally fixed it by setting this value `set_asset_host_to_callback_url: false` in my `/config/facebooker.yml`

- Note- for heroku apps this ha to be in the `production:` section of the facebooker.yml